# C: Segfault Using Free()

Tags: c

I have an array of pointers to structs that I am trying to using `free()` on once they are no longer needed. Below is how these structs are setup:

```
typedef struct {
    SDL_Surface *sprite;
    SDL_Rect rect;
} Laser;

Laser *fireLaser(char *sprite, int x, int y) 
{
    Laser *laser = malloc(sizeof(Laser));

    laser->sprite = loadSurface(sprite);
    laser->rect.x = x;
    laser->rect.y = y;

    return laser;
}

game->playerLasers[player->laserCount++] = fireLaser("images/laser.bmp", (player->rect.x, player->rect.y);
```

Once one is no longer needed, I attempt to use `free()` on it.

```
SDL_FreeSurface(game->playerLasers[i]->sprite);
free(game->playerLasers[i]);
```

I compile this with `free(game->playerLasers[i]);` and get no warnings or errors. The program runs, but as soon as `free()` runs, I get a segmentation fault.

When I run the program with `valgrind` I oddly do not get the segmentation fault, but I do get the following output once `free()` is ran:

```
==2010== Invalid read of size 8
==2010==    at 0x4012D8: spawnGrunts (main.c:196)
==2010==    by 0x4013FC: updates (main.c:219)
==2010==    by 0x4016CD: main (main.c:277)
==2010==  Address 0xcfce9c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==2010==    at 0x4C2AD90: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2010==    by 0x4012FF: spawnGrunts (main.c:197)
==2010==    by 0x4013FC: updates (main.c:219)
==2010==    by 0x4016CD: main (main.c:277)
==2010==  Block was alloc'd at
==2010==    at 0x4C29BBE: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2010==    by 0x400E65: loadGrunt (main.c:105)
==2010==    by 0x4011FE: spawnGrunts (main.c:182)
==2010==    by 0x4013FC: updates (main.c:219)
==2010==    by 0x4016CD: main (main.c:277)
==2010== 
==2010== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2010==    at 0x4C2AD90: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2010==    by 0x4012FF: spawnGrunts (main.c:197)
==2010==    by 0x4013FC: updates (main.c:219)
==2010==    by 0x4016CD: main (main.c:277)
==2010==  Address 0xcfce9c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==2010==    at 0x4C2AD90: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2010==    by 0x4012FF: spawnGrunts (main.c:197)
==2010==    by 0x4013FC: updates (main.c:219)
==2010==    by 0x4016CD: main (main.c:277)
==2010==  Block was alloc'd at
==2010==    at 0x4C29BBE: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2010==    by 0x400E65: loadGrunt (main.c:105)
==2010==    by 0x4011FE: spawnGrunts (main.c:182)
==2010==    by 0x4013FC: updates (main.c:219)
==2010==    by 0x4016CD: main (main.c:277)
```

Would anyone be able to give me a hint on this one?

Comment: Are you sure you are not corrupting the heap somewhere else in your code?

Comment: why just not using `Laser` without pointers? means without allocating/freeing? after all it's a small structure, can be copied without issues. (Maybe you're freeing the structs more than once)

Comment: When you allocate the laser, you increment a count: `player->laserCount++`. When you `free` that laser, the entry in the array needs to be removed, and the count needs to be decremented. I guessing that you aren't doing that, and the result is that you have dangling pointers in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Running your program under valgrind , you will most of the time not crash because you are running inside a memory space created by valgrind which is more forgiving for your program so to say.

You will usually not have compilation error on free unless trying to free a non-pointer type. But it will crash at the execution time because you will be trying to free a bad adress.

I would be very interested in seeing your function in charge of freeing thoose ressources , the complete one.

Are you in any place keeping track of the size of your array ?
Setting the array[i] to NULL to signal that it has been freed and is no longer usable ?

Always set your pointers to NULL when they are not usable.

Comment: It may be easier to link to my code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/azurepancake/space-man/blob/master/main.c). The function I'm trying to handle the clean up in is `shootLasers()`. Right now I just reset my array[i] back to 0 once it approaches it's max.